# Reputation got minus when an answered question was removed by the author

Tags: support, reputation

I am a newbie on Stack Overflow, trying to learn as much as possible, but this time I am stuck with a situation. I answered a question, where I got 25 reputation points, but the question is now removed by the author and those 25 points were also managed from my account. Why?

[image]

Comment: In this case, the user had requested deletion of the question, indicating that the problem was specific to their situation and unlikely to help anyone else. Usually, we don't delete questions upon request that have upvoted answers, but the moderator involved decided that this question wouldn't be able to help others and deleted it in response to the asker's flag.